# Chrome Extension KeyPress

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Is there anyway to send keyboard events for "left & right arrow keys" through a Chrome extension? I know that client-side javascript cannot send keyboard events, so I was wondering if Google Chrome had any browser APIs to simulate keyboard presses.

Comment: You want to listen or emulate the key strokes?

Comment: Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26816306/934239) - where CTRL + SHIFT + ALT + S was sent from an extension (ironically, by injecting a script into the page's context)