# Chrome extension firing keypress event

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, keyboard-events

This was [my original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34991280/chrome-extension-executing-webpages-defined-keypress-event?noredirect=1#comment57716578_34991280) and was taken to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17152932/chrome-extension-how-to-send-keydown-event-to-pages-input) very kindly by @rsanchez and @Xan. I would have loved to further ask on the link that they provided for me, but I don't have enough reputation to comment and so I'm having to make a new question here.

So my problem is that I'm developing a chrome extension in which I would like to get message from my server using Pusher and upon this message arriving, I would like to open up the appropriate chat and put the message I recieved from the server onto a textarea with id `messageInput` and fire the `keypress` event defined in the page's script.

I now understand that doing

```
var $message = $("#messageInput");
var e = $.Event("keypress", {keyCode: 13}); //keypress defined for enter
$message.text(myMessage);
$message.trigger(e);
```

won't work because it doesn't really call the real `keypress` event of the page's script.

And because I'm using a pusher module, I would like to not do the injection method since from what I understand, it's not possible to pass message from my content script to the injected script.

So I would like to use the `KeyboardEvent` method as suggested by the question that @rsanchez and @Xan pointed out. So I've tried it in the console first, only to see the returned value "true" with no events occurring at all. So how should I implement the following into my code?

content_script.js

```
...
channel.bind('returned_message', function(data) { 
    // returned_message is the message from server
    var $message = $("#messageInput");
    var e = $.Event("keypress", {keyCode: 13});
    $message.text(data.message);
    console.log($message.text());
    $message.trigger(e);
});
```

here's what I figure I should implement instead of `$.Event`:

```
var e = new KeyboardEvent('keypress');
e.code = 13;
document.querySelector("#messageInput").dispatchEvent(e);
```

Thank you in advance.

## EDIT

Here's the excerpt of the code that I found from the page's native script:

```
...
$msgInput.keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode == 13 && !e.shiftKey) {
      var msg = $msgInput.val().trim();
      if(msg.length > 0) {
        sendMsg(msg);
        $msgInput.val('');
      }
      e.preventDefault();
    }
});
...
```

where at the beginning of the script `$msgInput` was defined as `$msgInput = $("#messageInput")`.

Comment: Have you considered that the code listens to an event other than `keypress`?

Comment: @Xan I have overviewed the native script of the page and have confirmed that my intented element, the textarea with id `messageInput` has a `kepress` event. I'll update my question with the code excerpt of that keypress part

Comment: Take a look at [this answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26863396/934239), maybe it will help

Comment: @Xan Thank you so much it works!!! :D But I just have a quick question about this method. It's injecting a script with a fixed message right? So would simply reloading the page everytime I want to post a different message from the previous one work? From what I've found I think I saw from somewhere that the injected scripts do not get "removed" by simply reloading the page?

Comment: Injected scripts are just dynamically created `<script>` tags (which in this case are set to self-destruct after executing, even). They won't be present on reload, but your content script will be loaded again. If your logic requires a page refresh, **think again and do it better**.

Comment: Would you mind if I close this as a duplicate again? Or, if you prefer, could you post your adapted code as an answer?

Comment: @Xan Ahh okay I see that last line of the solution sets the script to self destruct upon execution. Thank you very much :D And yes, I'd prefer it to be closed as a duplicate. Thanks again :D