# Writing a Chrome Extension for triggering a chrome shortcut

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

Basically, I want to create a chrome extension to trigger a keyboard shortcut for `open new tab in same tab-group` and `pop-out the current tab in new chrome window` like this there are couple other tasks i want to accomplish using assigning keyboard shortcut.

I am new to developing Chrome extension but thought to learn.

**Here are some things I found:**

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37993631/trigger-shortcut-in-a-chrome-extension) asks something similar but its answer says, it's not possible. But I think there are extensions already exist which does some similar tasks.

have a look at this: [New tab in group - keyboard shortcut](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/new-tab-in-group-keyboard/hodhmojdnjljopdihkoniodkacnpimjf)

and also this: [Duplicate tab shortcuts](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/duplicate-tab-shortcut/klehggjefofgiajjfpoebdidnpjmljhb)

Is there anyone who can guide me towards the right documentation or right place to learn how to build chrome extension for this task?

Comment: You can't "trigger a chrome shortcut" indeed but you can implement what the action does by using [chrome.tabs.group](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/tabs/#method-group) and [chrome.windows.create](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#method-create) (you'll give it an existing tabId). Note that you can trivially inspect the source code of those extensions either in devtools or on the disk or in crxviewer.

Comment: @wOxxOm appreciate your reply. I just checked their code after posting this question as you said from chrome devtools. it's their `background page` where the magic happens. Thanks for the links you've provided.