# How to press any keyboard key programmatically using js or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I am trying to press "windows" + ";" key using javaScript/Jquery.Is there any way to do that?

Comment: this is not really the place to seek suggestions for a "yes" answer question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26816306/125981

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new [`KeyboardEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent) with `metaKey` and `keyCode` properties set as following:

```js
document.addEventListener('keypress', (event) => {
  console.log('Meta Key?', event.metaKey);
  console.log('Key Code', event.which);
});

document.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keypress', {
  metaKey: true, // On Windows, this is "window" key
  keyCode: 44 // This is keyCode of comma on Windows-US
}))
```

BUT, I'm not sure about browser support of this behavior.

Here's the list of `keyCode`s: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode

Hope this helps.